# Parsing street addresses by gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to parse street addresses with gsub, but I have hard time to understand regular expressions and how to use them correctly. The main problem is that street names consists one or more words, some addresses have apartment number and letter, some don´t. I would like parse all parts of the address to a different variable.

Here is an example:

```
Data1 <- data.frame(address = c("Wagon street 6", "Oscar de la Rosa Street 11 A", "Night street 35 B 2"))

Data1

>Data1$sname <- NA
>Data1$snumber <- NA
>Data1$anumber <- NA
>Data1$anumber <- NA

>Data1$sname <- gsub("(+.)\\s[^W]+$","\\1", Data1$address)
> Data1

                       address sname snumber anumber aletter
>1               Wagon street 6 Wagon      NA      NA      NA
>2 Oscar de la Rosa Street 11 A Oscar      NA      NA      NA
>3          Night street 35 B 2 Night      NA      NA      NA
```

All help and ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Start by keeping the street name. Try this: "($[^A-z])"

Answer (score 6):

I had requirement to do a lot of USA addresses parsing some time ago in R. As you have mentioned addresses can be  pretty messy. I have also tried to do the regular expressions but it was hell so I gave up.

My solution was to use python's [usaddress library](https://github.com/datamade/usaddress) from R. Please check this example:

```
library('rPython')

address = "Wagon street 6"

python.exec('import usaddress')

python.exec(paste0("addressObject = usaddress.parse('",address,"')"))

add <- python.get( "addressObject" )
```

Of course you have first to install that python library.  Check docs from the previous link for more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, addresses are not from US :(

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need?

```
gsub("(\\D+)\\d.*","\\1",Data1$address)
#[1] "Wagon street "            "Oscar de la Rosa Street " "Night street "
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It was helpful. Do you happen to have any idea how to parse those other elements after the street name?

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea: use strsplit with "street" as split. Use tolower to make things a bit easier. I created a Data1$sid (street id) column which after the loop stores the numbers and letters of the address. If you want further splitting I guess something similar will work. UPDATE: same tweaking (splitid) does it for your example. Not the cleanest of codes and not using regex but hopefully it'll help.

```
    Data1 <- data.frame(address = c("Wagon street 6", "Oscar de la Rosa Street 11 A", "Night street 35 B 2"))

Data1$sname <- NA
Data1$sid <- NA
Data1$snumber <- NA
Data1$aletter <- NA    
Data1$anumber <- NA

Data1$address<-tolower(Data1$address)
splitaddress<-strsplit(as.character(Data1$address), split = "street")
for(i in 1:length(splitaddress)){
  Data1[i,"sname"]<-splitaddress[[i]][1]
  Data1[i,"sid"]<-splitaddress[[i]][2]
}

splitid<-strsplit(Data1$sid, split=" ")
for(i in 1:length(splitid)){
  Data1[i,"snumber"]<-splitid[[i]][2]
  if(length(splitid[[i]])>2){
  Data1[i,"aletter"]<-splitid[[i]][3]
    if(length(splitid[[i]])>3){
      Data1[i,"anumber"]<-splitid[[i]][4]
    }
  }
}

Data1
                           address             sname snumber aletter anumber
1               wagon street 6            wagon        6    <NA>    <NA>
2 oscar de la rosa street 11 a oscar de la rosa       11       a    <NA>
3          night street 35 b 2            night       35       b       2
```